# How do I upload a new resume on Stack Overflow jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I need to update my resume on Stack Overflow jobs, but I couldn't find any option to do so.

If I remember correctly, while applying for jobs earlier it would give an option to upload a resume for that specific position. But while applying for roles now, it just uploads my previous resume without giving any option to upload a new one. It does have a remove button next to my resume, but I do not want to remove it without knowing how to upload a new one.

[image]

Also, is there a way I can have more than one resume uploaded on Stack Overflow jobs and can select one of them while applying for a job?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

1. Go to "Developer Story" tab.
2. On the right side click blue button "Job preferences".
3. Now you are here: "Edit Profile & Settings" tab.
4. Scroll down until you see "Saved resume".
5. If you want to upload updated resume: click "remove", then "Drag & drop your resume".

Comment: It looks like this has changed at some point.

Comment: In between 3-4 you might need to click on "Job Preferences" on the side-bar. Scroll down and you'll find the resume section there. Otherwise this is still correct.

Answer (score 10):

Once you click on `Remove` the following section will appear:

[image]

and that's how you can upload a new resume

Comment: can i save more than one version of resume, to be later used through a drop down or similar options ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not something we currently support. Feel free to ask a new question and tag it as [tag:feature-request]. I can't guarantee it will be implemented, but it's certainly a good way to collect feedback on it (and I can say [we have implemented a lot of them](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request%20status-completed%20jobs?mode=all))

Comment: where are those options? I don't find them

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it changed.

It's now under **Edit Profile and Settings**

1. Got to SO **Profile** : Click on your photo (upper right)
2. Click on **Edit profile and settings** (below search bar at top of page)
3. Scroll to near the end for **Resume**.

[image]

*And near the bottom of that section:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are currently not applicable.

The option to load resume has been moved to 'Job Preferences' section and scroll to the bottom and look for 'Saved Resume' section
[image]

[image]