# Upload multiple resume versions

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

SO jobs should provide the functionality to upload more than one version of resume, where user should be able to select one through a drop down or similar options while applying for a specific position.

Comment: What you're describing is a cover letter and not a resume.

Comment: Not necessarily @George, although I do see where you're coming from. I have definitely had different versions of a resume and handed them in depending on what sort of position I am applying for. For example I have one each for front and back end web development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload new resume on stackoverflow jobs?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352615/how-to-upload-new-resume-on-stackoverflow-jobs)

Comment: @SagarV in that question [g3rv4 has said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352615/how-to-upload-new-resume-on-stackoverflow-jobs#comment494880_352625) to create this thread as a feature request.

Comment: FWIW, this is a feature other job sites have so it's not like the OP is asking for something unheard of or odd. Customizing your resume to the position you're hiring for is also pretty common advice for job hunters.

Comment: @George, with so many different technologies out there, i go with different resumes tailored with specific requirements like that of java developer and machine learning